# how to add event listener to dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have swiper which works perfectly with existing elements. But when i scroll down my script creates dyncamically elements and my swiper are not work because at beggining it doesnt add event listiner.

```
var swiperContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper1')
        swiperContainer.forEach(function (elem) {
            var swiper = new Swiper(elem, {
                spaceBetween: 30,
                pagination: {
                    el: elem.parentElement.querySelector('.swiper-pagination1'),
                    clickable: true,
                    dynamicBullets: true,
                },
                navigation: {
                    nextEl: elem.parentElement.querySelector('.swiper-button-next1'),
                    prevEl: elem.parentElement.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev1'),
                },
            });
        })
```

I tried this using jquery still didnt work. I know it works if i remove this event listener and add again after loaded more elements. Is there any way to to do it better ?

Comment: What event listener are you talking about here? I don't see any in the code you have shown so far.

Comment: Are you actually talking about the loop over those `.swiper1` elements? Are you adding more of _those_ later on, and want to initialize swiper for them? Well then you will have to do that _after_ those new elements have been added - you can't "loop over" and add a swiper to elements, that don't exist yet.

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: ok guys, Sorry about this

Comment: @CBroe as you said I took it into function and after aI adding more later on I initialize swiper for them too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your goal was to enable dynamically created HTML components to be compatible with the Swiper plugin. In order to accomplish this, Swiper elements were dynamically detected and initialized as new elements are added to the DOM using MutationObserver and event delegation. Thus, items that are created dynamically can also easily make use of Swiper capabilities.

```
var targetNode = document.body;

var config = { childList: true, subtree: true };

var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(node) {
                if (node.classList && node.classList.contains('swiper1')) {
                    var swiper = new Swiper(node, {
                        spaceBetween: 30,
                        pagination: {
                            el: node.parentElement.querySelector('.swiper-pagination1'),
                            clickable: true,
                            dynamicBullets: true,
                        },
                        navigation: {
                            nextEl: node.parentElement.querySelector('.swiper-button-next1'),
                            prevEl: node.parentElement.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev1'),
                        },
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(targetNode, config);



$(document).on('click', '.swiper1', function() {
    var swiper = new Swiper(this, {
        spaceBetween: 30,
        pagination: {
            el: $(this).parent().find('.swiper-pagination1'),
            clickable: true,
            dynamicBullets: true,
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: $(this).parent().find('.swiper-button-next1'),
            prevEl: $(this).parent().find('.swiper-button-prev1'),
        },
    });
});
```